# Mean of floats in pandas gives unexpected Nan

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate mean of rows of floats but I can't understand why I get NaNs as result.

```
print(dfdiameters.head())
  dcyr2     dcyr1
0  4.047077  2.615053
1  4.081549  2.634745
2  4.115329  2.653720
3  4.148420  2.671981
4  4.180827  2.689535
```

I checked that no NaNs are present in any columns.

```
print (dfdiameters.isna().any())
dcyr2    False
dcyr1    False
dtype: bool
```

Calculate the mean by rows and create new column

```
dfdiameters = dfdiameters.assign(mean=dfdiameters.mean(axis=0))
```

Here is the result

```
print(dfdiameters.head())
      dcyr2     dcyr1  mean
0  4.047077  2.615053   NaN
1  4.081549  2.634745   NaN
2  4.115329  2.653720   NaN
3  4.148420  2.671981   NaN
4  4.180827  2.689535   NaN

dfdiameters.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7928 entries, 0 to 7927
Data columns (total 3 columns):
dcyr2    7928 non-null float64
dcyr1    7928 non-null float64
mean     0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 185.9 KB
```

I can't understand what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the mean for the wrong axis. `df.mean(axis=0` calculates the mean along the index (or row) axis, so the output is something like

```
>>> dfdiameters.mean(axis=0)

dcyr2     0.18424
dycr1     0.2432
dtype: float64
```

Then clearly you can't assign this to a column, since the shape isn't the same - so `df.assign` just bails out and gives you a NaN column. What you want is the mean along the column axis, i.e. `dfdiameters.mean(axis=1)` or equivalently `dfdiameters.mean('columns')`.

Comment: In fact, I want to obtain the mean of each row like that for thirst row: 0  4.047077  2.615053  3.331065

Comment: @chris2lamb Yes - the mean _of each row_ is the mean _along the column axis_ (left to right). Just a terminology mixup.